# Not able to load base64 image

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, base64

while loading my HTML page , I have an onload function written in AngularJS which will get a base64 string of an image file from the server and I stored this base64 string in $scope.product.image. when I try to display this base64
string , I am getting ERR_INVALID_URL error in console.

Error message looks like this : **GET : data:image/jpg;base64,9j_4AAQSK.......... net: ERR_INVALID_URL**

my HTML looks like this

```
<section ng-show="product.image">
            {{product.image}}  /* This actually displays the content of base64 string. This confirms that value is reaching properly*/
            <img ng-src="{{'data:image/jpg;base64,'+product.image}}"/>
</section>
```

my app.js looks like this

```
$scope.onload = function()
{
    $http({method:'GET', url:'rest/product/onLoad'})
    .success(function (response){
        $scope.product.image = response.image;

    });
};
```

I tried with   `<img data-ng-src="data:image/jpg;base64,{{product.image}}">`   but no luck.

How to load a base64 string as image ?

Comment: Cannot see any problems with your code. have u tried copy the `ng-src` value and put it in the browser address bar to check if the data-url works?

Comment: when i try to load ng-src value ( i.e data-ng-src="data:image/jpg;base64,**base64 string value**), it says that this site can't be reached. Is there any problem with my base64 string.
I wrote a webservice where it will convert an image from local machine (i.e c:\images) to base64 and send it as  a response to angularJS..
In angularJS, I have assigned the response value to $scope.product.image. When I try to load this value using ng-src, I am getting this error.

anything am I missing??

Answer (score 1):

The error u get means that the data url itself is not right.

Since your prefix is correct, there must be problems in the base64 string you get.

Try put the data url in browser's address bar and check if it works.

Comment: when i try to load ng-src value ( i.e data-ng-src="data:image/jpg;base64,**base64 string value**), it says that this site can't be reached. Is there any problem with my base64 string.
I wrote a webservice where it will convert an image from local machine (i.e c:\images) to base64 and send it as  a response to angularJS..
In angularJS, I have assigned the response value to $scope.product.image. When I try to load this value using ng-src, I am getting this error.

anything am I missing??

Comment: Maybe u should check if the base64 generated in your webservice works first. If it is right, when u put `data:image/jpg;base64,base64 string value` in the browser's address bar, there will be the image in the window. If what in the webservice is correctly generated, maybe u should check if it is the same as what u get at client-side (in angularjs).

Comment: I received the same value from webservice. I checked this by displaying the $scope.product.image value in html and it is displaying properly.
I wrote a seperate java code taking this base64 value as input, decoded to image and wrote it in a image file and the image is coming properly.

Comment: Umm that looks weird. could u try adding a charset value? like `data:image/jpeg;charset=utf-8;base64,base64 string value`, or are u sure your image is in `jpeg` format?

Comment: No luck with adding charset. I converted an jpg image file to base64 in webservice. My conversion logic looks like this
`FileInputStream imageInFile = new FileInputStream(imageFile);
            byte imageData[] = new byte[(int) imageFile.length()];
            imageInFile.read(imageData);
            
             imageDataString = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(imageData);`

If conversion logic is the problem, then through standalone java code, I am able to decode the image. I think some problem with loading mechanism in HTML

Comment: Then I have no idea where is the problem. If u find the solution, pls let me know :D.

Answer (score 1):

Call image data thru a function like this:

```
<img data-ng-src="{{getImage(product.image)}}" />
```

in controller:

```
$scope.getImage = function(data){
    return 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try using as the below:

```
ng-src="data:image/jpg;base64,{{product.image}}"
```